# Stress-Strain Relation in thin layer : Why should divide Force by Thickness?

Tags: forces, elasticity, stress-strain

I have question about equation (2) which is the stress-strain relation.
The left side means strain so the right side should be (Stress/Young's modulus).
And Stress can be calculated by dividing the force by the "Area".
However by equation (2), Stress is being calculated by dividing the force by the "Thickness".
In the case of thin layer, stress can be calculated using not area but thickness?...
Force/thickness?...um...

What is the physical meaning of E*t(mutiply of Young's modulus and thickness)?

I'm confused. Please help me.

The related whole paper link is this : https://wp.optics.arizona.edu/optomech/wp-content/uploads/sites/53/2016/10/chen-1979.pdf

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is one of nomenclature. You don't have stress defined as force divided by thickness. In the equations, $T$ is not force but force per unit length. This is common for plane stress/strain problems, although they are abusing terminology a bit.